# Sending a value from inside a callback function to express router

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

When I'm saving a new author from a POST, I'd like to return a message that the new Author has been saved. (I'd also will eventually want to return something if the author already exists) The problem that I'm having is that although the author gets save in the DB, I cannot write to `res.locals.messages` from inside the callback parameter of author.save(). (Also, note that createAuthor is an array of calls - I'm not sure if this makes get the value of `result` more difficult.)

How can I pass the value of `result` to the router?

route:

```
router.post('/', authorController.createAuthor, (req, res) => {
    res.json({ messages: res.locals.messages})
})
```

controller:

```
exports.createAuthor = [

check('firstName', 'First name must be specified').isLength({min: 1}).trim(),
check('lastName', 'Last name must be specified').isLength({min: 1}).trim(),
sanitizeBody('firstName').trim().escape(),
sanitizeBody('lastName').trim().escape(),


(req, res, next) => {

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    var author = new Author({
        firstName: req.query.firstName,
        lastName: req.query.lastName
    });

    if (errors.isEmpty()) {

       //Edit: added find before save function:
        const query = {$or:[{firstName:{$regex: req.query.firstName, $options: 'i'}},
                {lastName:{$regex: req.query.lastName, $options: 'i'}}]} //TODO this regex fails if a parameter is missing.

        Author.findOne(query).sort([['lastName', 'ascending']]).exec((err, author) => {
            if (err) {
                return next(err)
            }

            if(!(author ==null)){
                var result = {status: "Author already exists: ", author_id: String(author.id)}
                res.locals.messages = result;
                next();
            }

        });


        author.save(function (err, newAuthor) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err)
            }

            var result = {status: "New author saved", author_id: String(newAuthor.id)}
            res.locals.messages = result;

        });
    }
    next();

}
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `next` *after* you have handled the save and set the `res.locals` value:

```
exports.createAuthor = [

check('firstName', 'First name must be specified').isLength({min: 1}).trim(),
check('lastName', 'Last name must be specified').isLength({min: 1}).trim(),
sanitizeBody('firstName').trim().escape(),
sanitizeBody('lastName').trim().escape(),


(req, res, next) => {

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    var author = new Author({
        firstName: req.query.firstName,
        lastName: req.query.lastName
    });

    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
        author.save(function (err, newAuthor) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err)
            }

            var result = {status: "New author saved", author_id: String(newAuthor.id)}
            res.locals.messages = result;
            next();


        });
    } else {
        // Remember to do something about these non-empty errors!
        next(new Error('Got more than 0 errors'));
    }

}
];
```

Also, don't forget to handle the case where there is a non-zero number of  validation errors :)

Comment: Thanks you, Chris. I added a function to check if an author exists before saving.  The result of the find is `Author already exists:` but, the new author is saved a second time. How can I make sure that the new author is not saved a second time after it is confirmed to already exist in the DB?

Comment: I've tried setting a flag from find ...  give me a second to update my original code.

Comment: When `Author.findOne(query).sort` is called, afterwards it will immediately go to the next operation and execute `author.save`. *After* that, the callback for `Author.findOne(query).sort` will be called and you'll check the result, but by that time it's already trying to save the new author! You'll need to put the `author.save` function *inside* the callback for `Author.findOne(query).sort` and only call it if the result is good.

Comment: Based on your original question and your follow up code, I think you are trying to write callbacks without a strong understanding for how callbacks work. You should do some research into callbacks before continuing much further, or you'll have a lot of trouble! I might recommend [starting here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_callbacks_concept.htm).

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I am doing kind of a blind run here but, I was able to get this working using your comments. I'll be going over them again.

Comment: Glad to help. Happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

Using Chris Foster's comments I was able to get this working:

```
exports.createAuthor = [

check('firstName', 'First name must be specified').isLength({min: 1}).trim(),
check('lastName', 'Last name must be specified').isLength({min: 1}).trim(),
sanitizeBody('firstName').trim().escape(),
sanitizeBody('lastName').trim().escape(),


(req, res, next) => {

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    var author = new Author({
        firstName: req.query.firstName,
        lastName: req.query.lastName
    });

    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
        //TODO - Fix this query.
        const query = {
            $or: [{firstName: {$regex: req.query.firstName, $options: 'i'}},
                {lastName: {$regex: req.query.lastName, $options: 'i'}}]
        } 

        Author.findOne(query).sort([['lastName', 'ascending']]).exec((err, existingAuthor) => {
            if (err) {
                return next(err)
            }

            if (!(existingAuthor == null)) {
                var result = {status: "Author already exists: ", author_id: String(existingAuthor.id)}

                res.locals.messages = result;
                next();
            } else if (existingAuthor == null) {

                author.save(function (err, newAuthor) {
                    if (err) {
                        return next(err)
                    }

                    var result = {status: "New author saved", author_id: String(newAuthor.id)}
                    res.locals.messages = result;
                    next();
                });

            }
        });
    }
}
];
```